# All international SOs are down

Tags: bug, status-completed, international-sites

It seems that all international SOs are down now:

> [image: no SO]

I'm unable to open:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Same for:

- https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We're in the middle of fixing this. Should be back up shortly.

Comment: apple.stackexchange.com went down as well!

Comment: High latency in vi.stackexchange.com but no complete blackout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was a bug in some localisation code that caused an issue during a build. A fixed build is rolling out as I post this, and those sites should be back up shortly.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. +1

Comment: Build has completed, should be back up now